# AngularJS 2 calling Sharepoint Web service

Tags: json, rest, angular, sharepoint

The below code is throwing Error, the web service call is not returning json it seems ....

private _url = "https://us.sharepoint.com/sites/poc/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + "Micro" + "')/items";

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

getCMPosts() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
    this._url = "https://us.sharepoint.com/sites/poc/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + "Micro" + "')/items";
    console.log("URL 1: " + "https://us.sharepoint.com/sites/poc/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + "Micro" + "')/items");
    return this.http.get("https://us.sharepoint.com/sites/poc/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + "Micro" + "')/items", headers)
        .map(this.extractData)
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log("URL 2: " + "https://us.sharepoint.com/sites/poc/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + "Micro" + "')/items")
    console.log("Response Status: " + res.status);
    console.log("res.headers: " + res.headers);
    console.log("Response Text: " + res.text);
    console.log("Response To String: " + res.toString());
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}
```

Error in image please check
[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skk4q.png)

Comment: The error seems to be wrong json format.. Please check your json or mapping of json is correct

Comment: do this `console.log("Response Text: " + res.text());` to see the content. Now your are printing the function instead of executing the `text()` function! :)

Comment: Thanks after changing text to text() i get the below  
                                                               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://us.sharepoint.com/sites/poc/_api/" >
 <entry m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
  
  <content type="application/xml">
   <m:properties>
    <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ID>
    <d:ContentTypeId>0x01003A6D1C0AD2232446AC3923F1EA1D433C</d:ContentTypeId>
    <d:Title>111111111111</d:Title>
   </m:properties>
  </content>
 </entry>
</feed>